# A couple MySQL Questions

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

1. When I `OPTIMIZE`, `REPAIR`, or `ANALYZE` a MySQL table, will this stop all other operations from running until the process is complete (`INSERT`, `SELECT` etc.)? Should I frequently `ANALYZE` a table?
2. If multiple users are doing `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT` etc. operations at the same time on different locations throughout my site, will all the operations properly execute amidst the high load? Or is there certain code I should set up to make sure they get executed properly?

Need further clarification? I'll be glad to give more.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html
2. This is something that the database management system needs to worry about. You can't really do anything about synchronization.

Comment: Thank you very much for that link. It's pretty neat - I can do all 4 operations with one line of code. But, it does lock the table.

Answer (score 3):

1. All 3 operations will create a read lock. OPTIMIZE and REPAIR will create write lock. So you can not do any farther reading operation if ANALYZE is being run and no read/write operation when OPTIMIZE and REPAIR is run.
2. Its not ensured that query sequence of one user will not overlap the query sequence of another user. You should use [Transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).

Comment: Are you saying that a MySQL command may never get executed, because it gets overlapped by another one?Note: I don't care whether all the operations are performed at the SAME TIME or not, I just want to make sure they all get executed.

Comment: I said overlapped, not overrided. One user can send 3 queries and other send 4. The last 4 queries may run in between the 3 queries of first user. This is overlapping. This can happen. But all queries will be executed. To stop this non-atomic behaviour, Use transaction.